# QAF | Switch off logging to console (Eg. INFO c.q.q.a.ui.WebDriverCommandLogger - command: )

Tags: log4j, qaf

I would like to switch off the logging in the console which happens during the run. I have tried adding log4j.rootCategory=OFF in log4j.properties inside the "resources" folder. I have also seen some answers asking to move log4j.properties inside the "src" folder if the config is not picking up during the run. I have tried all possible workarounds.

Even if any direct java solution is available to switch off "INFO c.q.q.a.ui.WebDriverCommandLogger - command:" into console will be also helpful.

log4j.properties:

```
log4j.rootCategory=OFF
log4j.appender.console.Follow=true
#log4j.logger.com.qmetry.qaf=CONSOLE, LOGFILE
# Set the enterprise logger category to FATAL and its only appender to CONSOLE.
log4j.logger.org.apache.axis.enterprise=FATAL, CONSOLE

# CONSOLE is set to be a ConsoleAppender using a PatternLayout.
log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.Threshold=INFO
#log4j.appender.CONSOLE.Follow=true

log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=[%c{1}] - %m%n

# LOGFILE is set to be a File appender using a PatternLayout.
log4j.appender.LOGFILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.File=${outputDir}/isfw.log
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.Append=true
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.Threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.Follow=true
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.layout.ConversionPattern=[%t] %d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] %m%n
#%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n

log4j.logger.com.qmetry.qaf.automation.integration=resultUpdationLog

# LOGFILE is set to be a File appender using a PatternLayout.
log4j.appender.resultUpdationLog=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.resultUpdationLog.File=resultUpdation.log
log4j.appender.resultUpdationLog.Append=true
log4j.appender.resultUpdationLog.Threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.resultUpdationLog.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.resultUpdationLog.layout.ConversionPattern=%-6r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n

log4j.additivity.com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step=false
log4j.logger.com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step=DEBUG, SCENARIOLOGFILE
log4j.appender.SCENARIOLOGFILE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.SCENARIOLOGFILE.File=${outputDir}/scenario.log
log4j.appender.SCENARIOLOGFILE.Append=true
log4j.appender.SCENARIOLOGFILE.Threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.SCENARIOLOGFILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.SCENARIOLOGFILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{HH:mm:ss} %m%n

log4j.logger.com.qmetry.qaf.automation.ws=DEBUG, file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.file=${outputDir}/ws.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1GB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.conversionPattern=%d{[dd.MM.yyyy] [HH:mm:ss]} %p [%t] %c (%F:%L) - %m%n
```

Maven - pom.xml

```
<project
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.qmetry</groupId>
    <artifactId>qaf-blank-project-maven</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>qaf-blank-project-maven</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <testSuiteFile>config/testrun_config.xml</testSuiteFile>
        <sourceVersion>1.8</sourceVersion>
        <targetVersion>1.8</targetVersion>
        <qaf.version>3.0.0</qaf.version>
        <qaf-support-ws.version>3.0.0</qaf-support-ws.version>
        <selenium.version>3.141.59</selenium.version>
        <test.results.dir>test-results</test.results.dir>
        <run.time>${maven.build.timestamp}</run.time>
        <lib.dir>${project.basedir}/lib</lib.dir>
        <resource.dir>${project.basedir}/resources</resource.dir>
        <output.dir>${test.results.dir}/${run.time}</output.dir>
        <maven.build.timestamp.format>dd_MMM_yyyy_hh_mm_aa</maven.build.timestamp.format>
        <testng.report.title>IQe - Rapid Test Report</testng.report.title>
    </properties>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>qaf</id>
            <url>https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/dist</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>jai</id>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty-releases</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.qmetry</groupId>
            <artifactId>qaf</artifactId>
            <version>${qaf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.qmetry</groupId>
            <artifactId>qaf-support</artifactId>
            <version>${qaf.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.qmetry</groupId>
                    <artifactId>qaf</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.qmetry</groupId>
            <artifactId>qaf-support-ws</artifactId>
            <version>${qaf-support-ws.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerVersion>${sourceVersion}</compilerVersion>
                    <source>${sourceVersion}</source>
                    <target>${targetVersion}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.8</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${sourceVersion}</source>
                    <target>${targetVersion}</target>
                    <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
                    <complianceLevel>${sourceVersion}</complianceLevel>
                    <aspectLibraries>
                        <aspectLibrary>
                            <groupId>com.qmetry</groupId>
                            <artifactId>qaf</artifactId>
                        </aspectLibrary>
                    </aspectLibraries>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>${testSuiteFile}</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                    <reportsDirectory>${test.results.dir}/${run.time}</reportsDirectory>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <org.uncommons.reportng.xml-dialect>testng</org.uncommons.reportng.xml-dialect>
                        <org.uncommons.reportng.escape-output>false</org.uncommons.reportng.escape-output>
                        <log4j.configuration>file:///${resource.dir}/log4j.properties</log4j.configuration>
                        <outputDir>${output.dir}</outputDir>
                        <test.results.dir>${output.dir}/html</test.results.dir>
                        <json.report.root.dir>${test.results.dir}</json.report.root.dir>
                        <json.report.dir>${output.dir}/json</json.report.dir>
                        <selenium.screenshots.dir>${output.dir}/img</selenium.screenshots.dir>
                        <selenium.screenshots.relative.path>../img</selenium.screenshots.relative.path>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>[1.0,)</versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                                            <goal>compile</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <execute />
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @user861594 I have added the below dependency to pom.xml. After adding the below dependency "Log4j.properties" inside the "resources" folder started working.

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
      <version>2.14.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks that slf4j implementation loaded from one of the dependency. you can check dependency tree to find out and exclude it. Alternately you can add log4j slf4j dependency and exclude other globally (for example logback). Below is example for ivy dependency management:

```
<dependency org="org.slf4j" name="slf4j-log4j12" rev="1.7.31"/>

<!-- global exclude -->
<exclude org="ch.qos.logback" />
```

Same can be done for maven or gradle as well.

Comment: I'm using Maven... I have updated my question with my pom.xml. I couldn't find slf4j in it.. I have tried playing with log4j.configuration dependencies..

Comment: it may be transitive dependency. You can check maven dependency tree.